# How to find the sum of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{3 n}}{(3 n) !}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I'm really stuck with this problem and I hope some of you could give me a hint.

Consider the functions: $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{3 n}}{(3 n) !}, \quad f^{\prime}(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{3 n+2}}{(3 n+2) !}, \quad f^{\prime \prime}(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{3 n+1}}{(3 n+1) !}, \quad f^{\prime \prime \prime}(z)=f(z)$$
I need to find the sum of each of these series.

My first thought was to show that:
$$f(z)+f^{\prime}(z)+f^{\prime \prime}(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{3 n}}{(3 n) !}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{3 n+2}}{(3 n+2) !}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{3 n+1}}{(3 n+1) !}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n}}{n !}=e^{z}$$
And then solve this differential equation.

However, officially I haven't had a course in differential equations. So is there another way I can solve this using basic Complex Analysis? I hope some of you can guide me in the right direction, what theorems could be useful?

Comment: Which differential equation? What you wrote shows that the sum of those series is $e^z$. What else do you want?

Comment: Write down the series for $$e^{\omega x} \ e^{\omega^2 x} \mathsf{and} \ e^x $$ here $\omega$ is the cube root of unity

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi Where $\omega$ is a cubic root of the unity! Also named $j$.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/857693/42969

Comment: @JoseCarlosSantos I want find the analytic functions of f(z), f'(z) and f''(z), respectively. So what each individual sum is equivalent to.

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi  I have written down the series, but I'm not sure I see what to do about them? Can you maybe give a hint?

Answer (score 3):

In general, it is possible for us to extract components of power series by playing with roots of unity. Particularly, let's say

$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nz^n
$$

converges absolutely for some $z\in\mathbb C$. If we set $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/q}$ then

$$
\frac1q\sum_{r=0}^{q-1}\zeta^{-ra}f(\zeta^rz)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{qk+a}z^{qk+a}\tag1
$$

Consequently, we get

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty{z^{3k+1}\over(3k+1)!}=\frac13\sum_{r=0}^2 e^{-2\pi ir/3}\exp(e^{2\pi ir/3}z)
$$

Proof for (1):

Given $f$ converges absolutely at $z$, we can plug in the power series expansion for $f(z)$ to get

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{r=0}^{q-1}\zeta^{-ra}\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n\zeta^{rn}z^n
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nz^{n}\left(\sum_{r=0}^{q-1}\zeta^{r(n-a)}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

If $n\equiv0\pmod q$, then

$$
\sum_{r=0}^{q-1}\zeta^{r(n-a)}=\sum_{r=0}^{q-1}1=q
$$

Otherwise we have $\zeta^{n-a}\ne1$:

$$
\sum_{r=0}^{q-1}\zeta^{r(n-a)}={\zeta^{q(n-a)}-1\over\zeta^{n-a}-1}=0
$$

Consequently, the purpose of sum of roots of unity in (1) is to extract coefficients from power series.

Comment: Okay, this might be the method intended. However, I have never seen this before. Is this usually something that is usually covered by some theorem, or should this be obvious?

Comment: I edited the answer and put a proof for that, which is based on the properties of summing roots of unity.

Comment: @Tom This formula popped up while I was answering a question in [some Chinese community](https://www.zhihu.com/question/402384841/answer/1292044630)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\omega$ be the cube root of unity then denote $f_1$ by $e^{\omega x}$,$f_2$ by $e^{\omega^2 x}$ and $f_3$ by $e^x$

$$\begin{align*}f_1 &= \sum_{n\ge0} \left(\dfrac{x^{3n}}{(3n)!} + \omega \dfrac{x^{3n+1}}{(3n+1)!} + \omega^2 \dfrac{x^{3n}}{(3n+2)!}  \right)\\
f_2 &= \sum_{n\ge0} \left(\dfrac{x^{3n}}{(3n)!} + \omega^2 \dfrac{x^{3n+1}}{(3n+1)!} + \omega \dfrac{x^{3n+2}}{(3n+2)!}  \right)\\
f_3 &= \sum_{n\ge0} \left(\dfrac{x^{3n}}{(3n)!} + \dfrac{x^{3n+1}}{(3n+1)!} +  \dfrac{x^{3n}}{(3n+2)!}  \right) \end{align*} $$

Add all of them and get your result

Comment: Or in real terms, $e^z+2e^{-z/2}\cos\tfrac{z\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Comment: yes you are correct @J.G.

Comment: Oh, actually, we need to divide by $3$.

Comment: Okay, I can see that adding all these functions (and dividing by 3) will give me the function f(z). But I'm trying to understand where this comes from. This method is completely new, and not something I have ever seen before.

What was your approach? How would you know that adding these three types of functions would be the right answer?

Comment: @Tom this comes from $\omega^4 = \omega$ and  sum of cube roots of the unity is zero